# How to put a ignoreCase

Tags: java

I want to put a ignore Upper/Lower case, punctuation, and spaces. Here is the code I want to invoke it into:

```
public static boolean isPal(String s)
{
    if(s.length() == 0 || s.length() == 1)
        return true;
    if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length()-1))
        return isPal(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));
    return false;
}
```

Comment: A simple way to remove case considerations is to force your String `s` to be lowercase or uppercase using the `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` methods of the `String` class. As for the spaces and punctuation you would have to keep moving forward in the string until you found a valid character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try adding the line:

```
s = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}\\s]", "");
```

at the start of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to convert your string to lower or upper case and do all the comparisons, e.g.

```
public static boolean isPal(String s)
    {

        s = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");

        // Or if you want to allow digits
        //s = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");


        // Do all your comparisons
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the string to either case and use it for processing -

```
public static boolean isPal(String s) {
    s = s.toLowerCase(); // or  s.toUpperCase()

    if(s.length() == 0 || s.length() == 1)
        return true;
    if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length()-1))
        return isPal(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));
    return false;
}
```

And to ignore the punctuation use can use the regex given below. Add more characters that you need to ignore and escape them using a backslash `\`

```
[?:\\/\.]
```

Add it to the `replaceAll()`  method to replace with nothing.